# Canvas toBlob just generates a transparent image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out canvas's toBlob feature. On my page I have `<img id="img"/>` and further down I have a script that I'm trying to have populate it with an image.

What am I doing wrong? It seems to populate the `src` of the image, but it's completely transparent instead of the expected blue square.

```
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
c.width = 128, c.height = 128;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d", {alpha:false});
function generate(hex){
    return function(b){
        ctx.fillStyle = hex;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
        document.getElementById("img").src = URL.createObjectURL(b);
        }
    }
c.toBlob(generate("#abcdef"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob(callback)` method will generate a Blob containing an image representing the canvas state at the moment this method was called.
Then, asynchronously, it will call the passed *callback* with the resulting Blob as only parameter.

In you code, when you call `toBlob()`, nothing is drawn on your canvas yet, so the resulting Blob will contain a transparent image.
You are only going to draw on the canvas after this Blob has been generated, but this change will not get reflected in the already generated image.

So instead do

```js
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
c.width = 128, c.height = 128;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d", {alpha:false});
function generate(hex){
  // draw before toBlob is called
  ctx.fillStyle = hex;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
  // following callback will get executed after the image is generated
  return function(b){
    document.getElementById("img").src = URL.createObjectURL(b);
  };
}
c.toBlob(generate("#abcdef"));
```

```html
<img id="img">
```